# Quadratic form of function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Assume real function $f\in C^2(\mathbb{R}^m)$,$f(0)=0$,$\nabla f(0)=0$.How to prove $f$ can be represented by
$ f(x)=\Sigma_{i=1}^m\Sigma_{j=1}^m x_i x_j a_{ij}(x)$
and $a_{ij}(x)$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}^m$ and $a_{ij}=a_{ji}$ for all $x$.
I want to use Taylor expansion with Lagrangian remainder,but it's hard to say the relation between Hesse matrix $H_f(\xi)$ with $x$.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Taylor formula with integral remainder (called Laplace remainder sometimes). To see how it works you can write
\begin{align*}
f(x) - f(0) &= \int_0^1 \frac{d}{dt} f(tx) dt\\
&= \int_0^1 \nabla f(tx) \cdot x dt \\
&= x \cdot \int_0^1  \nabla f(tx) \times 1dt \\
&= x \cdot \left[ \nabla f(0) - \int_0^1 (t-1) Hess_f(tx)xdt \right] \\
&= \nabla f(0) \cdot x + x^T \left[ \int_0^1 (1-t) Hess_f(tx)dt \right]x
\end{align*}
and then set
$$
a_{ij}(x) = \int_0^1 (1-t) \frac{\partial f^2}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}(tx)dt 
$$